# LXD containers drops ICMP between one another

Tags: networking, bridge, lxd

So I stumbled across an issue that I cannot figure out. I have setup two host machines each with two LXD VM containers. Both are running LXD via Snap. One host is running Ubuntu 22.04 with two Ubuntu 22.04 containers. The other host is running Debian 12 with two Debian 12 containers. I have setup netplan on the containers and installed bridge-utils etc on both hosts. I then configured a network bridge on both hosts and configured the containers on those hosts to use them, all of which is using the exact same configuration.

### Hosts

```
ip link add dev lxdbr0 type bridge
ip addr add 172.16.0.254/16 broadcast 172.16.255.255 dev lxdbr0
ip link set lxdbr0 up
```

### LXD Container 1

LXD Config

```
devices:
  lxdbr0:
    hwaddr: 00:16:3e:fb:7d:1c
    nictype: bridged
    parent: lxdbr0
    type: nic
```

Netplan

```
network:
  version: 2

  ethernets:
    enp0s0:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:16:3e:fb:7d:1c
      set-name: enp0s0
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 172.16.0.1/16
      routes:
        - to: 172.16.0.0/16
          via: 172.16.0.254
```

### LXD Container 2

LXD Config

```
devices:
  lxdbr0:
    hwaddr: 00:16:3e:fb:7d:8d
    nictype: bridged
    parent: lxdbr0
    type: nic
```

Netplan

```
network:
  version: 2

  ethernets:
    enp0s0:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:16:3e:fb:7d:8d
      set-name: enp0s0
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 172.16.0.2/16
      routes:
        - to: 172.16.0.0/16
          via: 172.16.0.254
```

This is working fine on the Ubuntu host, but I have some issues on the Debian host. Normal TCP is working fine, but for some reason it drops ICMP between the containers. I can ping each containers from the host, but I cannot ping one container from another. At first I thought there was a general connection issue, but I tried installing nginx on one of the container which is fully accessible via `curl` from the other container.

Like I mentioned above. Both configurations are the same on each host and their containers. Maybe Ubuntu's Cloud Init is the reason why this is just working on Ubuntu? But why only ICMP?

There are no iptables configurations made, no ufw or other firewall installed and configured.

I have gone through every `ip` command check that I can think of, and everything is showing the same configuration between both installations. I have tried tcpdump and various other monitoring options that I could find, and I cannot figure out why or where these packets are dropped.

Comment: Why is the host configured as a /16 if the others are all /24's?

Comment: Sry, mixed configuration paste, because I tried adding an LXD managed bridge later to see if that would solve anything.

Comment: Right, okay, and why do you have a custom route for 172.16.0.0/16 even though the systems are already on that subnet directly? Doesn't the route defeat the point of there being a bridge?

Comment: Because I am testing some alternatives for the server that I already have running, which uses macvlan as the main route. The bridge is only to allow containers to communicate internally, without going through my entire network. It's a mix of LXD and Docker containers, but for now I am just trying to get the LXD part working.

Answer (score 0):

It would seam that my Ubuntu installation has `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1` configured somewhere. Not sure where as I have looked through both `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.d/`. But everything has forwarding enabled by default which is not the case on the Debian installation. Enabling this does fix the issue, although I am unsure why this only affects ICMP Request packets. Not really a major network expert, but does a 'curl' http request not begin with an ARP packet? Find it strange that `curl` could get through but `ping` could not.